# Does firestore support collection level locks in transaction?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have worked in a mongodb, which is no sql database and it support document level locks only. As firestore is also no sql database, does it support document level locks or it allows collection level locks?

Comment: Are you asking about Realtime Database (which doesn't have documents) or Firestore (which does have documents)?

Comment: @DougStevenson My bad, question is for firestore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only operation you have for locking is document locking with [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).  There is no collection locking in Firestore.

Comment: What about creating a document in another collection (let's call it the document D in the collection B) that represents this collection (collection A).
If we build our system in a way that every time we update collection A we do it with a transaction that holds a lock to the document D (and we also perform required reads to collection A inside the transaction), would it behave like a collection level lock?